# How to get value from range datetime from date format to bigint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm new using postgresql and had difficult to convert datetime to bigint type. So my tables has column timecreated that datatype is bigint. I want to get value with range datetime format like dd/mm/yyyy example : **select * from mytables where timecreated_at between '01/09/2021' and '10/09/2021'** . How i can achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not convert datetime to `bigint`, you use `timestamp with time zone`. To convert a string to a `timestamp with time zone`, use the `to_timestamp` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use postgresql timestamp conversion to get the range in days like

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2021-09-10 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2021-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp) as days;
```